# Mapbox - Adding popup event to a layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use `mapbox-gl-js` API and have 2 layers with `id: 'A'` and `id: 'B'` on my Map.

```
map.addLayer({
    id: 'A',
    type: 'symbol',
...../*My code*/
});
map.addLayer({
    id: 'B',
    type: 'symbol',
...../*My code*/
});
```

I want add a popup when I click to layer with `id: 'B'`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
map.on('click', 'B', function (e) {
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML("POPUP!")
        .addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it Inline as above you can also do the following. Depending what you are doing this method may be more beneficial:

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
  .setHTML('</br>Property Marker 1');

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
  .setLngLat([-79.367196, 44.2197703])
  .addTo(map)
  .setPopup(popup);
```

This method also automatically creates the click event instead of needing to do it with Jquery, by using "setPopup" on the marker it will automatically show the HTML contents of popup when clicked.